# JIRA JQL for query contains does not work with the letter "A"

Tags: jira, jql

Here is my JQL :

```
project = XXX AND issuetype = Bug AND status in (Open, 'In Progress', Reopened) and summary  ~ '\\\\[A\\\\]'
```

JIRA return no result even I have tickets that contain the text "[A]" in the summary. It only doesn't work for "[A]", if i try with other letters, it works.
For example, the jql below works :

```
project = XXX AND issuetype = Bug AND status in (Open, 'In Progress', Reopened) and summary  ~ '\\\\[B\\\\]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the underlying search indexing mechanism (Lucene) doesn't store the square brackets. See [this answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/31449/jql-help-how-to-find-summary-that-starts-with-certain-characters) for a similar problem with angle brackets. Not ideal, but you could use an alternative series of characters to represent [A]. Also not ideal, but you could store [A] in a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about "[" brackets.
Search for all issues having text "A"
Search for all issues having text "B"
You can see that it is about character "A".

"**A**" is a reserve word in Jira.

You can find more reserve words in the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/search-syntax-for-text-fields-764478343.html#Searchsyntaxfortextfields-reservedReservedwords).